# Eclipse jre 1.5 > 1.8

Tags: java, eclipse

Can anybody convert these lines from jre 1.5 to 1.8?

Even tho if i put my eclipse project version to 1.5 my jar breaks.

```
  Map<String, byte[]> resources = new HashMap<>();
        Enumeration<JarEntry> enumeration = jar.entries();




   Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("com.kit.Application");
        Method main = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);




 if (main != null) {
            main.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{});


Class<?> applicationClass = applicationObject.getClass();

                Method setDockIconImage = applicationClass.getDeclaredMethod("setDockIconImage", new Class[]{Image.class});
                setDockIconImage.invoke(applicationObject, (Object) ICON_IMAGE);`
```

Comment: what's the problem? Errors? messages?

Comment: It just shows me this; http://prntscr.com/f3qpby

Comment: it says 1.5 or greater so using 1.8 java should fix this issue, why convert to  an older version of java when it says 1.5 or greater. just use java 1.8 version

Comment: What?.. My post is about converting to higher version, the project is in java 1.5 and changing jre will cause these errors...

Comment: So the current JDK/JRE that is bound in Eclipse or your project is below 1.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that your source code version is lower than java 1.5. This can be either configured on a project basis, or globally in eclipse.

Make sure you have the correct setting, if you checked "Enable project specfic settings" in the projects properties under java compiler, you need to specifiy the compiler compliance level there. If not checked, the workspace settings will be used, in which case you need would want to select Window/Preferences from the main menu bar and go to Java/Compiler to change the workspace settings.

Also note that automatic type inference using the diamond '<>' is an 1.7 feature. This is not supported in 1.5 and will probable lead to a non-specific error message from an 1.5 compiler.